# Change the atribute of the xml tree in python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, attributes

I have a problem with change of the atribute at the xml file.
My tree looks like that

```
<Objects>
<BigObj Version="2.2" Name="Something">
<ItemList>
<Item Name="s_1" Selected="false"/>
<Item Name="s_2" Selected="false"/>
<Item Name="s_3" Selected="true"/>
<Item Name="s_4" Selected="false"/>
</ItemList>
</BigObj >
</Objects>
```

And i need to check if "s_x"is in list of names and  if it is then change the value of Selected to true, if it's not to false (or keep it false)
I've tried to do that with this code:

```
lslist = ["s_1","s_4"]        
for child in root.findall("./Objects/BigObj/ItemList/Item"):
        for idx in lslist:
            if idx in child.find("Name").text:
                child.set('Selected', "true")
            else:
                child.set('Selected', "false")
```

But i have an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below works

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

lslist = ["s_1", "s_4"]

xml = '''<Objects>
<BigObj Version="2.2" Name="Something">
<ItemList>
<Item Name="s_1" Selected="false"/>
<Item Name="s_2" Selected="false"/>
<Item Name="s_3" Selected="true"/>
<Item Name="s_4" Selected="false"/>
</ItemList>
</BigObj ></Objects>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
items = root.findall('.//Item')
for item in items:
    item.attrib['Selected'] = str(item.attrib['Name'] in lslist)
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<Objects>
<BigObj Version="2.2" Name="Something">
<ItemList>
<Item Name="s_1" Selected="True" />
<Item Name="s_2" Selected="False" />
<Item Name="s_3" Selected="False" />
<Item Name="s_4" Selected="True" />
</ItemList>
</BigObj></Objects>
```

Comment: That's works! Thank you so much that's great solutiuon =)